# Tabular fixed width

Tags: tables

I'm using the `p` column type in order to force the width of the columns of my table. However, the total width of the table becomes larger that the textwidth. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{tabular}{|p{.3\textwidth}|p{.45\textwidth}|p{.125\textwidth}|p{.125\textwidth}|}
\hline
a & b & c & d\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Is the source of the problem that `p` set the content width and doesn't account for the space between columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three factors you're not taking into account.

1. The paragraph indent
2. The intercolumn space
3. The rule widths (if you're using `array`)

Maybe

```
\usepackage{calc}
```

and then

```
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{
  |p{.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|
   p{.45\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|
   p{.125\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|
   p{.125\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|
}
```

would do. Or you may want to shrink more the wider columns. Remember that there's a `\tabcolsep` wide space at either side of each column.

[image]

Note that if you're using the `array` package, the above code should become

```
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{
  |p{.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|
   p{.45\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|
   p{.125\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|
   p{.125\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|
}
```

There are five rules which have to be taken care of; according to the LaTeX manual, the leftmost rule logically belongs to the first column; the other rules belong to the column preceding them.

Comment: Why is there a `2\arrayrulewidth` for the first column and not the last one? From the output I see there has to be n+1 `\arrayrulewidth`, and so I could also dispatch it across the columns...

Comment: @s__C Sorry, it shouldn't be there

Comment: if you try `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` then you'd see why you need it no?

Comment: @s__C - One *could* subtract `1.25\arrayrulewidth` from each for the four columns (for `n=4`, `1.25=(n+1)/n`), rather than subtract `2\arrayrulewidth` from the first column and `1\arrayrulwidth` from the remaining three. However, given the (rather small) value of `\arrayrulewidth`, you'd be hard pressed to notice any practical difference between the two approaches.

Comment: @Mico as long as you do not turn `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` ON...

Comment: @s__C - I'm afraid I don't understand your point. If I run either egreg's or my code, the only difference I notice if the `geometry` package is loaded (with *or* without the option `showframe`) is a change in the default value of `\textwidth`. How is this change supposed to invalidate the claim I made earlier?

Comment: I'm not contesting the first part of your comment @Mico, but the one on `\arrayrulewidth` being discarded.

Comment: @s__C - Whether or not `\arrayrulewidth` is "discarded" (disregarded might be a better term) depends on whether or not the `array` package is loaded.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than compute the column widths yourself, you can let LaTeX handle the job if you load the `tabularx` package and use that package's `X` column type.

If the ratios of the column widths to the width of the text block are as `0.45`, `0.3`, `0.125`, and `0.125`, the following setup will achieve your purpose. The only "rule" to remember is that the sum of the `\hsize`s  must equal the number of columns -- `4` in the example you gave. To set the relative column widths, then, just multiply the ratios given above by `4`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|%
   >{\hsize=1.8\hsize}X|
   >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X|
   >{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X|
   >{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X|}
\hline
a & b & c & d \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

In case you're curious about the details: If the table is supposed to take up the width of the text block (i.e., if it has width `\textwidth`), has `n` columns (here: `n=4`), and the columns are separated by vertical rules, the table's *usable* width is `\textwidth-2n\tabcolsep-(n+1)\arrayrulewidth`. The `tabularx` environment then apportions the usable width according to the ratios `0.45`, `0.3`, `0.125`,  and `0.125`. (To obtain the *actual* width of a column, add `2\tabcolsep` to the column's *usable* width.)